# Hide ActionBar Tab on Keyboard visible

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have an activity that have attached to `ActionBar` a few `Tab` (4 by now).
I would like to hide the **Tab** line as the keyboard shows, and then show the Tab again as the keyboard is closed.

I've searched several answers in here, but no one seems to do what I want (everyone use external libraries for hiding the Tabs on `listView` scroll, or "delete" dynamically the tab and then recreate them).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: well hiding the actionbar is trivial, just call getSupportActionBar().hide(); and since the tabs are part of the ActionBar they should also be hidden

Comment: And how can I bind it to the keyboard show "event"?

Comment: there is no such kind of events. What you can do is to use a ViewTreeObserver

Comment: Referring to your first comment: I don't want to hide the whole ActionBar, but only the Tab line below.
Referring to your second comment: how should I use the ViewTreeObserver?

Comment: then probably switching between and `getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`    and `getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)` could work

Comment: @blackbelt Hi. Is it possible to animate the hide/show action?

Comment: what you can do is to retrieve the action_bar_container, that's a view, start an animation and use OnAnimationEnd to show/hide @noooooooob

Comment: @blackbelt would that show/hide the whole action-bar or only the tabs? I mean, I only want to hide the tabs.